# mutex in linux page faulted memory

Tags: c, linux, mutex

I've been having a strange concurrency issue with linux 2.6 and a mutex located in mmap file backed memory.  It's a latch manager module.  Does the page fault logic restart an instruction entirely that includes a lock prefix?  It's acting like it doesn't include the lock prefix when it restarts.  If I set the MAP_LOCKED attribute in the mmap call, the problem clears up.  Anyone with any experience?

```
//  mode & definition for hash latch implementation

enum {
  Mutex = 1,
  Write = 2,
  Pending = 4,
  Share = 8
} LockMode;

// mutex locks the other fields
// exclusive is set for write access
// share is count of read accessors

typedef struct {
  volatile ushort mutex:1;
  volatile ushort exclusive:1;
  volatile ushort pending:1;
  volatile ushort share:13;
} BtSpinLatch;

//  wait for other read and write latches to relinquish

void bt_spinwritelock(BtSpinLatch *latch)
{
  do {
#ifdef  unix
  while( __sync_fetch_and_or((ushort *)latch, Mutex | Pending) & Mutex )
    sched_yield();
#else
  while( _InterlockedOr16((ushort *)latch, Mutex | Pending) & Mutex )
    SwitchToThread();
#endif
  if( !(latch->share | latch->exclusive) ) {
#ifdef unix
    __sync_fetch_and_or((ushort *)latch, Write);
    __sync_fetch_and_and ((ushort *)latch, ~(Mutex | Pending));
#else
    _InterlockedOr16((ushort *)latch, Write);
    _InterlockedAnd16((ushort *)latch, ~(Mutex | Pending));
#endif
    return;
  }

#ifdef unix
  __sync_fetch_and_and ((ushort *)latch, ~Mutex);
  sched_yield();
#else
  _InterlockedAnd16((ushort *)latch, ~Mutex);
  SwitchToThread();
#endif
  } while( 1 );
}

void bt_spinreadlock(BtSpinLatch *latch)
{
ushort prev;

  do {
#ifdef unix
    while( __sync_fetch_and_or((ushort *)latch, Mutex) & Mutex )
      sched_yield();
#else
    while( _InterlockedOr16((ushort *)latch, Mutex) & Mutex )
      SwitchToThread();
#endif

//  see if exclusive request is granted or pending

    if( prev = !(latch->exclusive | latch->pending) )
#ifdef unix
      __sync_fetch_and_add((ushort *)latch, Share);
#else
      _InterlockedExchangeAdd16 ((ushort *)latch, Share);
#endif

#ifdef unix
    __sync_fetch_and_and ((ushort *)latch, ~Mutex);
#else
    _InterlockedAnd16((ushort *)latch, ~Mutex);
#endif
    if( prev )
      return;
#ifdef  unix
  } while( sched_yield(), 1 );
#else
  } while( SwitchToThread(), 1 );
#endif
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that creates and initializes your mutex in mmap memory?

Comment: I've attached the reader/writer exclusive request code.  It uses the lower bit of the ushort as a mutex.

Comment: And the latch is created and initialized with a zero value.

Comment: Any reason why you don't put a process shared mutex and a condition variable in that shared memory?

Comment: Yeah, they're too big.  These reader/writer locks are ushorts.  I need them to protect hash table entries.

Comment: What does your reader lock code look like?

Comment: read lock code posted above.

Comment: When you ask about page fault and lock prefix, I presume you are trying to understand the behavior of this code if the code page was paged out while it was spinning, and then paged back in? Is this code in a shared library? If so, was the code compiled as position independent?

Comment: Yes, I want to ensure that the atomic instruction restarts at the lock prefix after a page-fault interrupts it.  The code is not currently in a shared library and is not compiled with PIC flag.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the delay introduced by the page faults exposes a race condition otherwise not seen.

I would suggest starting with `pthread_spinlock_t` (which is just an `int`) and making sure your software works correctly before implementing your own spinlock. The error could be elsewhere.

There are a few issues with that code:

1. Mixing access to `BtSpinLatch* latch` as `BtSpinLatch` and  `ushort` breaks aliasing rules leading to undefined behaviour. Make `BtSpinLatch` a `ushort` and stick to accessing bits using bitmasks and shifts only.
2. When a writer acquires the lock it clears `pending` bit even if there is another pending writer.
3. `__sync_fetch...` built-ins are obsolete and too expensive since they constitute a full memory barrier and they are invoked more times here than necessary. Use the [built-in functions for memory model aware atomic operations](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#_005f_005fatomic-Builtins).
4. Bit-fields bit order is platform dependent. The code assumes low-endian bit-fields.